# How to run wear app with minSdk 20 on Samsung Galaxy gear with sdk 17

Tags: android, google-api, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-gear

hello I have samsung galaxy gear for testing purpose, I have purchased it few days before. Its minimum sdk is 17, however I have made the project of wear with minimum sdk of 20 . As minimum sdk for wear is 20 in Android studio. So I can not run my app on that watch

And If i tries to edit the gradle file to minimum sdk 17 it gives me a following error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':wear:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 17 cannot be smaller than version 20 declared in library com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0

So what should I do as if I will remove this com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0 , it will then not let me work with google api's . What would be the suggested solution of this problem please help.

Comment: Which model of Galaxy Gear do you have?

Comment: its SAM-v700   . Samsung Galaxy gear <orange color>

Answer (score 2):

Galaxy Gear (Samsung SM-V700) doesn't have Android Wear OS, but Tizen OS - it was originaly released with Android (not Android Wear), but then Samsung replaced Android with Tizen in 2.2 software update. The only Samsung Gear device running on Android Wear right now is Gear Live.

If you want to develop for your Galaxy Gear you should go to this [website](http://developer.samsung.com/gear) and download Tizen SDK for wearable. You can develop Android apps for Galaxy Gear (not Android wear apps) if you haven't updated your device yet, but I wouldn't recommend it, beacause the newest software version is based on Tizen and you should focus on supporting the newest software version.

Comment: My watch is still on android , yes if I would update it , it would go to tizen , which I really do not want to be, SO in this case what should I do , I have made project in AS 0.8.1 So please tell me is there any way to test my project on this watch ?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, I would recommend you to update to Tizen and familiarize with Tizen SDK. In case you really want to stick to Android, you shouldn't create Android Wear Project, but instead create normall Android application (not using werable library) with minSdk 17 and adjust everything manually. There is almost no information about Android development for Galaxy Gear and also AFAIK there is no API or SDK released by Samsung which could help you in Galaxy Gear Android development. IMO updating to Tizen is the best solution.

Comment: If I update my device to TIzen would it be able to run my app which is in android ? because I do not want to waste time in understanding  tizen right now . So What would you say that Can I still able to run my project even after updating to tizen

Comment: Android on your watch is not a Android Wear. Way out for you is either sell it, or lear to develop for Tizen. Sorry.